# Difference between NOT LIKE and <> in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I noticed that I have many instances of `null` in my `table.prop`. As I do not want these returned I decided to make my query using `table.prop <> 'null'`. Since I am experimenting with performance I decided to also try `table.prop NOT LIKE 'null'`. Both queries return the same results in what seems to be the same amount of time.

**So I come to my question;**

What is the difference between `<>` and `NOT LIKE` in terms of performance *and* use?

Comment: Out of the two examples, I think `table.prop <> 'null'` would be faster. But i'd also stipulate that `IS NOT NULL` would be even faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table.prop NOT LIKE 'null'
```

...does not require the differentiation that `LIKE` normally provides.  I suspect that, because you didn't include any wildcard characters, the query engine simply converts it to `<>`.

So, in your particular case, it doesn't make any difference.  `<>` and `NOT LIKE` are not logically equivalent, however; you should read up on those to see how they differ.  In general, prefer `<>` unless you really do need the wildcard features of `LIKE`.